# unable to save dynamically created MemoryStream with rebex sftp

Tags: c#, sftp, rebex

I'm using `StreamWriter` to generate a dynamic file and holding it in a `MemoryStream`.  Everything appears to be alright until I go to save the file using [rebex sftp](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/).

The [example](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/tutorial-ftp.aspx#upload-download) they give on their site works fine:

```
// upload a text using a MemoryStream 
string message = "Hello from Rebex FTP for .NET!";
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
client.PutFile(ms, "message.txt");
```

However the code below does not:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.Write("test");
    } 
    client.PutFile(stream, "test.txt");
}
```

The file "test.txt" is saved, however it is empty.  Do I need to do more than just enable `AutoFlush` for this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing to the MemoryStream, the stream is positioned at the end. The PutFile method reads from the current position to the end. That's exactly 0 bytes.

You need to position the stream at the beginning before passing it to PutFile:

```
    ...
}
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
client.PutFile(stream, "test.txt");
```

---

You may also need to prevent the StreamWriter from disposing the MemoryStream:

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write("test");
writer.Flush();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
client.PutFile(stream, "test.txt");
```